# sorting after comparing

Tags: r

I have some problems createing formula, which compare two numbers and at the end program sort all numbers. I create (have) a vector `x` with values: `x <- c(5, 10, 2, 35, 1)` and function with name:  `SortFunc(x)`

Result at the end should look like this:

```
[1] 1 2 5 10 35
```

I did this function:

```
SortFunc <- function(x) {
  n <- length(x)
  repeat {
    spr <- FALSE
    n <- n-1
    for(i in 1:n) {
      if ( x[i] > x[i+1] ) {
        t <- x[i]
        x[i] <- x[i+1]
        x[i+1] <- t
        spr <- TRUE
      }
    }
    if (!spr) break;
  }
  x
}
```

When I run `SortFunc(x)`, I get this error:

```
Error in if (x[i] > x[i + 1]) { : argument is of length zero
```

Have anyone slution? If I change vector like `x <- c(5,8,7,30,1,100)`* I get true solution `([1]   1   5   7   8  30 100)`

Comment: What is wrong with `sort(x)`?

Answer (score 2):

Here's your function output from each loop:

```
R > SortFunc(c(5,10,2, 35, 1))
[1]  5  2 10  1 35
[1]  2  5  1 10 35
[1]  2  1  5 10 35
[1]  1  2  5 10 35
Error in if (x[i] > x[i + 1]) { (from #7) : argument is of length zero
```

So after 4 loops, it has been sorted, but during the last loop, they still changed the order, so `spr` is `True`, thus it does not break. Instead it continues to try `n <- n-1` making `n = 0`, which made the error.

Slightly modified your code, it works:

```
SortFunc <- function(x) {
  n <- length(x)
  repeat {
    spr <- FALSE
    for(i in 1:(n-1)) {
      if ( x[i] > x[i+1] ) {
        t <- x[i]
        x[i] <- x[i+1]
        x[i+1] <- t
        spr <- TRUE
      }
    }
    n <- n-1
    if (n == 1 | !spr) break;
  }
  x
}
```